Power Query Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type List
I'm trying to use Power Query to add a running total column to a table combining transaction records from several different bank accounts. I'm quite new to Power Query and M, and I'm following the first method in this tutorial:
How to Calculate the Running Total by Group Using the Excel Power Query – 2 Methods
But I'm getting stuck at the first hurdle. It works fine when I follow the syntax laid out in the tutorial:
= let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Amount],BufferedValues = List.Buffer(Source[Value]),RT = Table.FromColumns({Source[Value], fxRunningTotal(BufferedValues)},{"Value","Running Total"}) in RT

But I don't want to have to import this table to the workbook just to query it, I want to reference the query directly. When I try to do that like so:
= let Source = #"Query1"[Amount],BufferedValues = List.Buffer(Source[Amount]),RT = Table.FromColumns({Source[Amount], fxRunningTotal(BufferedValues)},{"Amount","Running Total"}) in RT

I get the following error:

⚠️ Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type List.
Details:
Value=[List]
Key=Amount

Can any experts lend a hand?

Where did #"Query1" come from?

I'm using Table1 and Query1 to stand in for the names of the table and query.

Yes, but what is the data source for Query1?

Oh, I see. It's pulling data from a CSV file. Table1 is that data pulled into a table in the Excel workbook, whereas Query1 is the query pulling the data from the CSV file. To keep things neat and tidy, I want to pull and combine all the data from various CSVs in Power Query and only show what's needed in the workbook.

Are your .csv files in the same folder? And do they have the same structure and column names? If so, and no unrelated .csv files are in the folder, use Data>>Get from folder to combine the files first. Load and Only create connection. From there,  you should be able to edit the original syntax by replacing Table1 with the new connection only query name.

Thanks for your help. The CSVs are not all in the same folder and do not all share the same structure as they come from different sources. I don't want to put them all in the same folder as they are currently organised by account and I only need the latest CSV from each one.
However, so far I've only imported one of them, using Get from CSV, combined the date and time columns and removed some unnecessary columns. Is it not possible to reference the query directly in this way?

It sounds like you have a lot of work to do since structures are different and in different locations. You need to create separate queries for you .csv data sources, transform to a common structure, and then append your queries. You can load intermediate queries as connection only before appending.

Thank you. I've done as you suggested in your second comment, with syntax = let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Query1"]}[Amount], etc but I get the following error as expected:

Expression.Error: We couldn't find an Excel table named 'Query1'.


As discussed in the comments, Get and Transform your .csv files, load them as Only create connection; then, Combine >> Append the connection only queries to your Query1. Load Query1 as Only create connection. Then model your Running Sum M Code after the following code which was tested and works in PQ. Note that your posted M Code returns the table RT whereas the following code returns table #Changed Type, which changes the column data types to integers.
let
Source = Query1,
BufferedValues = List.Buffer(Source[YourColumnToBeSummed]),

RT = Table.FromColumns(
{
    Source[YourColumnToBeSummed], fxRunningTotal(BufferedValues)
},
{
    "YourColumnToBeSummed",
    "Running Total"
}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RT,{{"YourColumnToBeSummed", Int64.Type}, {"Running Total", Int64.Type}})
in     
#"Changed Type"

Original code source: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/quickly-create-running-totals-in-power-query

Amazing! This works, thank you!

Excellent! Very glad it worked for you!
